# Format integers as fraction

Tags: excel

I have a list of fractions in Excel which I want to format as fractions, including integers. However, by default Excel formats integers as integers which is understandable.

Is there any way to force Excel to format, say, `4/4` as `4/4` instead of `1`?

I need it to be stores as values and not as text, so `'4/4` wont work. As I need to average a bunch of values from it afterwards.

Apparently I'm the first person ever to take issue with this, because google provides absolutely no help whatsoever :o

Comment: "I need it to be stores as values" what is the difference between the value `4/4` and the value `1`? They are the same number and you seem to want to store numbers rather than text.

Comment: Just me being anal about it :)
I'm just logging a bunch of data in which I have 4 tries at each, and then I log whether I make it 1/4, 2/4 etc. 4/4 just looks better than 1 and makes more sense for the viewer. I need it stored as values because I calculate an average number of tries afterwards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use a custom number format:

```
?/4
```

[image]

Comment: What if the denominator isn't 4? OP seems to want a format that would work for any fraction.

Comment: @JohnColeman, then he is out of luck since you can force to show denomitors, however, 4/4 will then show as 1/1, just as 2/4 will show as 1/2 and 2/8 shows as 1/4.

Comment: There also seems to be rounding issues if you try the custom format `#?/?`. It seems that OP doesn't want to just store a value but also in effect a history of what was typed.

Comment: OP's question is answered, but I agree with you, this probably will open the next question =).

Comment: Perfect! Nice and simple! The default format was # ?/4, but removing the # solved everything! thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe what you are trying to accomplish is doable outright, as fractions are really division problems.  However, with some formula trickery, you may be able to get something that will work for you.

If you place `'7/8` in cell `A1` and then use the following formula in cell `B1`

```
=DECIMAL(MID(A1,1,FIND("/",A1,1)-1),10)/DECIMAL(MID(A1,FIND("/",A1,1)+1,LEN(A1)),10)
```

The cell will display the decimal value of the "fraction", in this case `0.875` allowing you to change the denominator at will and still perform math functions.

This works because the formula slices up the "fraction" stored as text and converts it to a number and performs the math.